# Diseño de hoja PDF con ITextSharp o otra libreria ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015, pdf

necesito generar PDF con el siguiente estilo.
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

A lo que me refiero con (estilo) es el diseño como el logotipo en esa ubicación, el borde color verde al final de la hoja, y también al tamaño de la hoja en mi caso lo necesito letter(carta), quisiera saber como podría hacer esto, y si puedo usar iTextSharp o es necesario el uso de otra librería, dicha imagen anterior es una certificación la cual genere con FPDF de PHP, pero ahora necesito hacer eso mismo pero en ASP.NET MVC5.

Cualquier ayuda o recomendación sera de bastante utilidad.

Comment: ByGroxD, tres preguntas. Estas trabajando con C#?, los datos para el informe los estas obteniendo de una base de datos?, el reporte es para que lo descargue el usuario o para guardarlo en el disco dentro del servidor?

Comment: Hola, si los datos son traidos desde una base de datos, estoy usando ASP.NET MVC5, es para que el usuario los pueda descargar y si es posible que se guarden en el servidor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ya me enfrenté a una situación parecida. La solución a la que llegué fue crear una imagen con el formato necesario y después ponerla en el documento así:

```
Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
doc.SetMargins(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);

doc.Open();
Image logo = Image.GetInstance(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/cld/graphs/BG Vector.png"));
logo.ScalePercent(24f);
logo.SetAbsolutePosition(0f, 0f);
doc.Add(logo);
doc.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

...

doc.Close();
```

**¿Cómo funciona?**

1. Definimos el objeto `doc` como un documento de iTextSharp de tamaño `LETTER` (carta) y establecemos los márgenes a un punto (`1f` por ser de tipo `float`).
2. Una vez que inicializamos el documento (`doc.Open()`) creamos un objeto de imagen (del espacio de nombres `iTextSharp.text.Image`) y le damos la ruta de la imagen.
3. Una vez que establecimos la imagen a utilizar, la línea de `ScalePercent` obedece a [este tutorial para insertar imágenes](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/87/itextsharp-working-with-images) y en seguida colocamos la imagen en la posición `0,0` con `SetAbsolutePosition`.
4. Una vez que hemos hecho lo anterior, simplemente colocamos la imagen en el documento (`doc.Add(logo)`).
5. Para seguir editando libremente, colocamos una "nueva línea" (`Chunk.NEWLINE`).

Es importante recalcar que en mi caso *necesitaba un fondo completo*, mientras que en tu caso solo necesitas una parte superior y una inferior. En ese caso puedes usar dos imágenes en lugar de una y colocar la superior arriba (tendrás que buscar qué posición `x,y` es la conveniente para ti) y la inferior abajo (en `0,0`) ya que eso aligerará el peso del archivo final.

Otra cosa: la imagen debe estar hecha a una resolución apta para una impresión a 300 `dpi` ([¿Qué son los DPI?](http://www.fmedda.com/es/article/dpi_ppi)) para que la escala `24` funcione; esta debe ser (para cubrir toda la página) de `2550x3300` pixeles. En mi caso, utilicé una imagen apta para una impresión a 600 `dpi` en posición horizontal, por lo que mi resolución fue de `6600x5100` pixeles y mi escala no fue a `24` sino a `12`. Para generar mi imagen utilicé un software llamado [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/es/) pero puedes elaborarla como tú quieras.

---

**Servir el PDF en MVC**

Para poder entregar el PDF a través de un servidor Web, utilizo el siguiente código:

```
public FileResult GetPdf(string id, int año = 0, int mes = 0)
{
    // Primero declaramos el documento
    Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
    doc.SetMargins(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);

    string _dir = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Ruta/para/guardar/");
    if (!Directory.Exists(_dir)) Directory.CreateDirectory(_dir);

    FileStream _stream = new FileStream(string.Format("{0}/Mi PDF {1} {2}-{3}.pdf", _dir, id, año.ToString(), mes.ToString()), FileMode.Create);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, _stream);

    doc.Open();    
    /*
     * (Generación del PDF)
     */
    doc.Close();
    writer.Close();

    return File(string.Format("{0}/Mi PDF {1} {2}-{3}.pdf", _dir, id, año.ToString(), mes.ToString()), "application/pdf", string.Format("PDF descargado {0} {1}-{2}.pdf", id, año.ToString(), mes.ToString()));
}
```

**¿Cómo funciona? descarga del archivo**

1. Establecemos la ruta para guardar el archivo **en el servidor**, ya que es donde se generará el archivo. Si la carpeta no existe, la creamos.
2. Declaramos un `FileStream` que servirá para transmitir el archivo. Como parámetro recibe la ruta completa del archivo (la carpeta que definimos anteriormente + el nombre del archivo que vamos a generar) y declaramos la operación, que en este caso será crear el archivo (`FileMode.Create`) e instanciamos el creador de PDFs.
3. Generamos el PDF.
4. Declaramos el fin del documento (`doc.Close()` y `writer.Close()`).
5. Como retorno del método (que es un `FileResult`) damos un `File` (del espacio de nombres `System.Web.Mvc`) que toma como parámetros **la ruta del archivo** en el servidor, el **tipo de archivo** que va a descargar y *opcionalmente* el nombre con el que se debe descargar.

---

**Otras consideraciones**

De esta manera puedes colocar un texto acomodado en cierta región del documento y respetando los saltos de línea que sean necesarios:

```
BaseFont SourceSans = BaseFont.CreateFont(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.otf"), BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
iTextSharp.text.Font _standardFont = new iTextSharp.text.Font(SourceSans, 8, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);

#region Párrafo principal
Phrase _parrafo = new Phrase("Texto del párrafo, te recomiendo poner las variables con un string.Format.", _standardFont);
PdfContentByte _cb = writer.DirectContent;
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(_cb);
ct.SetSimpleColumn(_parrafo, 312f, 530f, 762f, 580f, 25, Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
ct.Go();
#endregion
```

En este bloque hice lo siguiente:

1. Queriendo usar una tipografía no común (SourceSans) la descargué (de [Font Squirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/), mi recomendación personal) y ubiqué el archivo en mi servidor.
2. En las dos primeras líneas hago referencia a la tipografía para poder utilizarla.
3. Siguiendo [este tutorial](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/82/itextsharp-adding-text-with-chunks-phrases-and-paragraphs) se coloca el párrafo que quieras con la tipografía que requieras (lo puedes ver también en la [documentación oficial](https://afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/docs-itextsharp/Index.html)).
4. Declaramos un `PdfContentByte` y `ColumnText` (no te preocupes, no se añade a ninguna tabla) (ambos del espacio de nombres `iTextSharp.text.pdf`) y colocamos esa *"columna"* conteniendo el párrafo en la posición `x, y, x', y'` que queramos. `x, y` son las coordenadas de la **esquina inferior izquierda** del párrafo, mientras que `x', y'` son las coordenadas de la **esquina superior derecha**. Esto no es cuánto espacio ocupará el texto, sino cuánto espacio *puede* ocupar como máximo.
5. Finalizamos la colocación con la sentencia `Go()`.

---

**Ejecución**

Tomando todos estos conceptos, tu código final debería quedar así:

```
public FileResult GetPdf(string id, int año = 0, int mes = 0)
{
    Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
    doc.SetMargins(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);

    string _dir = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Ruta/para/guardar/");
    if (!Directory.Exists(_dir)) Directory.CreateDirectory(_dir);

    FileStream _stream = new FileStream(string.Format("{0}/Mi PDF {1} {2}-{3}.pdf", _dir, id, año.ToString(), mes.ToString()), FileMode.Create);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, _stream);

    BaseFont SourceSans = BaseFont.CreateFont(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.otf"), BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
    iTextSharp.text.Font _standardFont = new iTextSharp.text.Font(SourceSans, 8, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);

    doc.Open();
    // Imagen superior
    Image logo = Image.GetInstance(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/logo.png"));
    logo.ScalePercent(24f);
    logo.SetAbsolutePosition(20f, 700f);
    doc.Add(logo);
    doc.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

    // Imagen inferior
    Image pleca = Image.GetInstance(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/pleca.png"));
    pleca.ScalePercent(24f);
    pleca.SetAbsolutePosition(0f, 0f);
    doc.Add(pleca);
    doc.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

    // Párrafo
    Phrase _parrafo = new Phrase(string.Format("Por medio de la presente hacemos constar que el señor {0}...", NombrePersona.ToUpper()), _standardFont);
    PdfContentByte _cb = writer.DirectContent;
    ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(_cb);
    ct.SetSimpleColumn(_parrafo, 312f, 530f, 762f, 580f, 25, Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    ct.Go();

    doc.Close();
    writer.Close();

    return File(string.Format("{0}/Mi PDF {1} {2}-{3}.pdf", _dir, id, año.ToString(), mes.ToString()), "application/pdf", string.Format("PDF descargado {0} {1}-{2}.pdf", id, año.ToString(), mes.ToString()));
}
```

Comment: amigo entiendo que el Servir el PDF en MVC va en mi controlador, pero, donde y como debería ir el código del principio que tenia Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);

Comment: Hola, acabo de añadir las instrucciones para que crees el párrafo. Ahora bien, respondiendo a la pregunta que me haces por aquí: ese `doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER)` debe ir **antes** del `FileStream`; puede ser desde el principio de tu acción, yo lo tengo como tercera línea en mi código solo después de dos validaciones `año = año == 0 ? DateTime.Now.Year : año; mes = mes == 0 ? DateTime.Now.Month : mes;`, puedes prácticamente copiar el segundo bloque de código que te puse en la respuesta y te debería funcionar :).

Comment: amigo una consulta necesito, que la imagen en la parte inferior aparezca de un ancho del 100%

Comment: Crea una imagen que sea únicamente la pleca verde. Guárdala en una resolución de, digamos, `2550x70` y haz lo del primer bloque: aplícale una escala del `24` y úbicala en las coordenadas `0, 0`. ¡No se te olvide agregarla al documento!

Comment: Acabo de actualizar la respuesta ya con un código que puedes probar :D

Comment: Como te has currau la respuesta tio! jajaj lo que se hace por 50 de repu XD

Comment: bro, como puedo hacer un Titulo? que se vea en Negrilla